# jquery ui selectable: make an option selected on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectable

I have the following HTML:

```
<ol id="selectable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">Option 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Option 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Option 3</li>
</ol>
```

I need, for example the first option, to be selected by default on page load. I use the following code without any luck:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#selctable li:first').addClass('ui-selected');
});
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You have a typo, missing an `e` in `#selctable` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You miss-spelled selectable.

```
$('#selectable li:first').addClass('ui-selected');​
```

check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cTfqT/)

Comment: Need to get some sleep I guess.

Answer (score 5):

You need to call `selectable()` before adding the class to the first `li`

```
$(function() {
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable().children().first().addClass('ui-selected');
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/N565p/)

Comment: +1 for help on adding a selection to the selectable programmatically.  There's no guidance on this in the jQuery Ui Selectable documentation.  I would believe this would be a pretty common requirement.

Answer (score 1):

attributeName - Use .attr() and set the value to true: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#selectable li:first').attr("selected",true);
});
```

See this question: [jQuery Cannot set "selected"="selected" via attr() on <option> elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729741/jquery-cannot-set-selected-selected-via-attr-on-option-elements)

Comment: selected is for options of the select element.. he has an OL

Comment: Was my fault, I up voted your response, because the error is miss-spelled as you said

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

```
$('#selectable :first-child').addClass('ui-selected');
```

please check the example: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MEJgb/42/)