# val("text") is not setting the option as selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to change the value of this select using `$('#mySel').val('1.5');` I have found several places that recommend doing it like this.  But for some reason it doesn't seem to be working, and instead just selects the first option `0.5`.  Does anyone know why this would not work?  Or what might work instead?  Here is the code I am using.

```
$('#mySel').val('1.5');
$('#courseset').trigger('create');

<select name="hours" id="mySel" data-mini="true" >
   <option value="0.5" >0.5</option>
   <option value="1.0" >1.0</option>
   <option value="1.5" >1.5</option>
   <option value="2.0" >2.0</option>
   <option value="2.5" >2.5</option>
   <option value="3.0" >3.0</option>
   <option value="3.5" >3.5</option>
   <option value="4.0" >4.0</option>
   <option value="4.5" >4.5</option>
   <option value="5.0" >5.0</option>
   <option value="5.5" >5.5</option>
   <option value="6.0" >6.0</option>
   <option value="6.5" >6.5</option>
   <option value="7.0" >7.0</option>
   <option value="7.5" >7.5</option>
   <option value="8.0" >8.0</option>
   <option value="8.5" >8.5</option>
   <option value="9.0" >9.0</option>
   <option value="9.5" >9.5</option>
   <option value="10.0" >10.0</option>
   <option value="10.5" >10.5</option>
   <option value="11.0" >11.0</option>
   <option value="11.5" >11.5</option>
   <option value="12.0" >12.0</option>
</select>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KZBfd/ <- Works for me. Most likely something else is causing the issue. Check your error console.

Comment: Aren't you trying to select a option ? otherwise here's a similar case [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496052/jquery-setting-the-selected-value-of-a-select-control-via-its-text-description) and this works for me too

Comment: @Vega I have checked the error console and it doesn't give any errors.  Is there some sort of error that could come from the jquery mobile or something?

Comment: @Eman I think it should be same.. but I am not sure.

Comment: Are you using $('#mySel').val('1.5'); before initialize your DOM element #mySel as your snippet could suggest it?

Comment: Is this `$('#mySel').val('1.5');` is wrapped inside DOM ready like `$(function () {  $('#mySel').val('1.5'); });`. That line would only work if that `#mySel` exist in DOM.

Comment: Or jQuery mobile's equivalent, like `pageinit` or so: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html.

Comment: @roasted What do you mean by initialize your DOM element.  I think it is valid because if i instead do `alert($('#mySel').val())` it returns the first option.

Comment: @Eman See Vega comment "That line would only work if that #mySel exist in DOM."

Comment: @Vega Yes, but if I can call `alert($('#mySel').val())` shouldn't it work to assign the new value also?

Comment: @Vega I use the line `$('#courseset').trigger('create');` right before I try and change the value.  shouldn't that create it in the DOM?

Comment: If `alert($('#mySel').val())` returns first option (that is `0.5`) then you are fine.. I am not sure why `.val()` is not working for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should match the option field without knowing its place in the DOM

```
$('#mySel option[value="1.5"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Comment: This selects the option only if nothing was selected yet.

Comment: Not according to my own testing. If you do have this issue, you need only first $('#mySel option').removeAttr('selected') to reset all options

Comment: No, the reason is that [un]setting attributes does not help, it only changes the `defaultSelected` property. Use `.prop("selected", true)` instead

Comment: Maybe there's a browser inconsistency then. I'm using Chrome and it works just fine.

Comment: Might also depend on the jQuery version. Use one that properly distinguishes between `.prop` and `.attr`. Chrome does implement the `defaultChecked` property correctly

Comment: if you could give me specific details on versions where this won't work, i'll be happy to confirm. i've tested against jquery versions 1.3 and 1.8

Comment: This question has already been asked. Check out [prop() vs attr()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5874652/1048572) and [Cannot set “selected”=“selected” via attr() on <option> elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3729741/1048572)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#mySel option").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == '1.5';
}).prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: Why not just `.val()`? jQuery `.val` handles it just fine.

Comment: @Vega: Yes, it should. Yet it does not work for the OP, do you know the reason? Btw this snippet does select an option by text content, not by value

Answer (score 0):

Try use .attr("selected", "selected).

You can also use nth-child to select the option, in your case, you can try the following:

```
$("#mySel :nth-child(3)").attr('selected', 'selected'); //selected option value=1.5
```

Comment: This selects the option only if nothing was selected yet.