# how to set an option being selected by jquery in ie?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, selected

I try to set an option being selected via its value.My code is out here.It works in FF and Chrome but not in IE.can anyone help me?

```
var province = $("#hideProvince").val();
if(province != ""){
  $("#province option[value='"+ province + "']").attr("selected", "selected");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `attr("selected", true)` instead of `attr("selected", "selected")`, I found this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729741/jquery-cannot-set-selected-selected-via-attr-on-option-elements)** it may be related to what you are looking for.

```
var province = $("#hideProvince").val();
if(province != ""){
  $("#province option[value='"+ province + "']").attr("selected", true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set `val()` on the `select` to update the selected option:

```
var province = $("#hideProvince").val();
if (province != ""){
  $("#province").val(province)
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/CNnLp/)