# IE9 not correctly running .each() jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two muti-selects where I can tranfer items back-and-forth, which is working perfect in all browsers. My problem is in IE9 the `.each()` does not seem to be running. Basically what I'm doing is running an `.each()` that will select all items in the desired multi-select before I submit. In IE9 when I click submit none of the items in `select2` never get selected.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9VDGN/1/)

**JQUERY**

```
/* multi-select handler */
$('#add').click(function()
{  
    return !$('#select1 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select2').removeAttr("selected"); 
});  
$('#remove').click(function()
{  
    return !$('#select2 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select1').removeAttr("selected");  
});

/* submit button handler */
$('#submit').click(function)
{
    /* select all items in select2 */
    $('#select2 option').each(function()
    { 
        $(this).attr("selected","selected");
    });

    /* check to see if any items were selected */
    if( $('#select2 option').length === 0 )
    {
        alert('no items selected');
    }
    else
    {
        alert('success'); 
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="multi-select-container">       
    <div class="multi-select-left">
        <select multiple id="select1">
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="2">Two</option>
            <option value="3">Three</option>
            <option value="4">Four</option>
            <option value="5">Five</option>
            <option value="6">Six</option>
        </select>             
    </div>  
    <div class="multi-select-center">
        <button id="add" class="btn btn-mini btn-add" style="display:block;margin:5px;">Add</button>
        <button id="remove" class="btn btn-mini btn-delete" style="display:block;margin:5px;">Remove</button>
    </div>
    <div class="multi-select-right"> 
        <select multiple id="select2"></select>               
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Cannot set "selected"="selected" via attr() on <option> elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729741/jquery-cannot-set-selected-selected-via-attr-on-option-elements)

Comment: Just tested in IE9 (http://jsfiddle.net/9VDGN/2/): your `.each` loop is running fine. Your problem is that `$(this).attr("selected", "selected")` isn't working.

Comment: Hm, interesting. I've obviously been looking at the wrong line of code. Thank you for pointing that out. I'm looking into what Jacob is saying about this being a duplicate. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing this :

```
$(this).attr("selected", "selected");
```

By this :

```
$(this).prop("selected", true);
```

Comment: @Mike: You don't need jQuery here. Just do `this.selected = true;`

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is [this](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8900) wontfix in jquery. I think you have to avoid the attr function.

Comment: That's about setting events using `attr`. In this code the only attribute set is `selected`, which is not an event. How are they related?